# Animation fill mode and opacity are not keeping the last style after animation ends

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to keep the `opacity` set at 1 at the end of an animation (it should be the last keyframe) using the `animation-fill-mode` set to `forwards`, but for some reason I'm missing it set the opacity back to 0 at the end of the animation.

Here the snippet of the elements I'm animating:

```
<div class="section active">
   <span>Il</span>
   <span>massaggio</span>
   <span>è</span>
   <span>l'unica</span>
   <span>forma</span>
   <span>di</span>
   <span>piacere</span>
   <span>fisico</span>
   <span>a</span>
   <span>cui</span>
   <span>la</span>
   <span>natura</span>
   <span>ha</span>
   <span>dimenticato</span>
   <div id="arrow-container">
     <img src="images/social-35-white.svg" id="arrow-down" alt="" class="image-2">
   </div>
 </div>
```

While here is the css with the animation:

```
span {
    color: transparent;
    animation: blur 10s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: blur 10s ease-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
span:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
span:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
span:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
span:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
span:nth-child(6) {
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
span:nth-child(7) {
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
span:nth-child(8) {
    animation-delay: 0.8s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
span:nth-child(9) {
    animation-delay: 0.9s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
span:nth-child(10) {
    animation-delay: 1.0s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.0s;
}
span:nth-child(11) {
    animation-delay: 1.1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.1s;
}
span:nth-child(12) {
    animation-delay: 1.2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
span:nth-child(13) {
    animation-delay: 1.3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.3s;
}
span:nth-child(14) {
    animation-delay: 1.4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.4s;
}


@keyframes blur {
    0%      {text-shadow:  0 0 100px #111; opacity:0;}
    5%      {text-shadow:  0 0 90px #111;}
    15%     {opacity: 1;}
    20%     {text-shadow:  0 0 0px #111;}
    80%     {text-shadow:  0 0 0px #111;}
    100%.   {opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes blur {
    0%      {text-shadow:  0 0 100px #111; opacity:0;}
    5%      {text-shadow:  0 0 90px #111;}
    15%     {opacity: 1;}
    20%     {text-shadow:  0 0 0px #111;}
    80%     {text-shadow:  0 0 0px #111;}
    100%    {opacity: 1;}
}
```

Why is it not keeping the opacity at the end?

Comment: You want to preserve opacity at the end?

Comment: @SwapnilSoni yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last keyframe is `100%  {opacity: 1;}` so this is the style that is retained... however this *isn't* the style that is making the text visible!

The text has `color:transparent` so opacity is not having any effect. The style that is actually making the text visible is `text-shadow:  0 0 0px #111;`, so you need to include this in your last keyframe:

```
100%   {opacity: 1; text-shadow:  0 0 0px #111; }
```

**Note**: I've kept `opacity` in case you have other elements not included here, but for the code you have here it is not actually doing anything :)

**Working Example:** 
You can see this working below, FYI I've made run for 2s so it's quicker to see it works :)

```css
span {
    color: transparent;
    animation: blur 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: blur 2s ease-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
span:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
span:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
span:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
span:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
span:nth-child(6) {
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
span:nth-child(7) {
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
span:nth-child(8) {
    animation-delay: 0.8s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
span:nth-child(9) {
    animation-delay: 0.9s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
span:nth-child(10) {
    animation-delay: 1.0s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.0s;
}
span:nth-child(11) {
    animation-delay: 1.1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.1s;
}
span:nth-child(12) {
    animation-delay: 1.2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
span:nth-child(13) {
    animation-delay: 1.3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.3s;
}
span:nth-child(14) {
    animation-delay: 1.4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.4s;
}


@keyframes blur {
    0%      {text-shadow:  0 0 100px #111; opacity:0;}
    5%      {text-shadow:  0 0 90px #111;}
    15%     {opacity: 1;}
    20%     {text-shadow:  0 0 0px #111;}
    80%     {text-shadow:  0 0 0px #111;}
    100%   {opacity: 1; text-shadow:  0 0 0px #111; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blur {
    0%      {text-shadow:  0 0 100px #111; opacity:0;}
    5%      {text-shadow:  0 0 90px #111;}
    15%     {opacity: 1;}
    20%     {text-shadow:  0 0 0px #111;}
    80%     {text-shadow:  0 0 0px #111;}
    100%   {opacity: 1; text-shadow:  0 0 0px #111; }
}
```

```html
<div class="section active">
   <span>Il</span>
   <span>massaggio</span>
   <span>è</span>
   <span>l'unica</span>
   <span>forma</span>
   <span>di</span>
   <span>piacere</span>
   <span>fisico</span>
   <span>a</span>
   <span>cui</span>
   <span>la</span>
   <span>natura</span>
   <span>ha</span>
   <span>dimenticato</span>
   <div id="arrow-container">
     <img src="images/social-35-white.svg" id="arrow-down" alt="" class="image-2">
   </div>
 </div>
```

*Also FYI you have an extra `.` in the line:* `100%.   {opacity: 1;}`

As you say, using `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` means that the element will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution, this is a reference for any other users asking about this: [MDN Docs for animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode).

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```css
span {
  animation: blur 5s ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
   opacity: 0;
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
span:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
span:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: 0;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
span:nth-child(5) {
  opacity: 0;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
span:nth-child(6) {
  opacity: 0;
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
span:nth-child(7) {
  opacity: 0;
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
span:nth-child(8) {
  opacity: 0;
    animation-delay: 0.8s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
span:nth-child(9) {
  opacity: 0;
    animation-delay: 0.9s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
span:nth-child(10) {
  opacity: 0;
    animation-delay: 1.0s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.0s;
}
span:nth-child(11) {
  opacity: 0;
    animation-delay: 1.1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.1s;
}
span:nth-child(12) {
  opacity: 0;
    animation-delay: 1.2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
span:nth-child(13) {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-delay: 1.3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.3s;
}
span:nth-child(14) {
  opacity: 0;
    animation-delay: 1.4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.4s;
}

@keyframes blur {
  0% { color: transparent; text-shadow:  0 0 100px #111;  }
  50% { color: transparent; text-shadow:  0 0 90px }
  100% { opacity: 1; color: transparent; text-shadow:  0 0 0px #111; }
}
```

```html
<div class="section active">
   <span>Il</span>
   <span>massaggio</span>
   <span>è</span>
   <span>l'unica</span>
   <span>forma</span>
   <span>di</span>
   <span>piacere</span>
   <span>fisico</span>
   <span>a</span>
   <span>cui</span>
   <span>la</span>
   <span>natura</span>
   <span>ha</span>
   <span>dimenticato</span>
   <div id="arrow-container">
     <img src="images/social-35-white.svg" id="arrow-down" alt="" class="image-2">
   </div>
 </div>
```